# How to display the last four blog posts using Json api on html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

display latest blog post wordpress in html static site?

html

```
<div id="content" class="content">
</div>
```

javascript

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON( "https://startupet.com/blog/wp-json/wp/v2/posts", function( 
    data ) {

     console.log(data);
     });  
     })
      </script>
```

"image post and title "

json file :
https://startupet.com/blog/wp-json/wp/v2/posts

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter your `data` object (aka queryset), which currently contains **all** of the `posts`.

Assuming that `data` fetches posts by id... Try `data.slice(-4)` to get the last 4 elements in the array or `data.slice(1,5)` to get the first 4. Or may need to call slice on `data.object.slice()`.

Comment: I'm not sure that the code works properly because it does not work

Comment: try `console.log(data.slice(-4));` to see if slice is filtering the data

Comment: or `data.object.slice(-4)`

Comment: and if you still can't figure it out do `console.log(typeof data));` and `console.log(typeof object));` to get clues about the kind of object you need to filter

Comment: You can this url api ,writeing code and display post weblog in html

Comment: Read the API documentation for range parameters of the `GET posts` method

Comment: ok im split 4 array . but how to set image and title to div tag